# x86 assembly read/write to file

Tags: c, assembly, x86, read-write

I'm currently trying to write to a file so far I have the following code to append to the file. Does anybody know why this isn't working? It runs fine but by the end nothing has changed.

```
filewritemode: .asciz "a"
filelocation: .asciz "/h/test.txt"

_main:  

push $filelocation
push $filewritemode
call _fopen
push $blabla
push %eax 
call _fprintf

push $result
call _printf
push $0
call _exit # exit the program
```

gcc is used in order to turn the source file into an .exe
$blabla is currently the string with some random chars that are ment for testing

Comment: How are you linking those library functions?

Comment: Also, shouldn't an assembly file have a _start function as the entry point?

Comment: You may have to create the file first. If you only "write to" a file ...and that file doesn't exist ...then nothing gets written. Creating a file is a different function. The same goes for opening and closing a file, it's sometimes a different function to filewrite

Comment: I guess blabla is your format string? Why do you push 4 uninitialized bytes between the format string and the file descriptor, before calling fprintf()? Also, maybe you should make sure to close the file before calling exit().

Comment: @ady the append mode for fopen() creates the file if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because you have pushed the parameters of `fopen` in the wrong order. Parameters must be pushed from last to first. Aside from that you are repeatedly pushing parameters, but you don't remove them again. In this case that works because you take a dive to `exit`, but if instead you would have returned with the `ret` instruction, you would have found that this would result in a crash as you would be jumping to one of the pushed parameters.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the arguments to `fopen` reversed and you are not checking for errors. In situations like this, `ltrace` may be your friend.